# SSSD ActiveDirectory SSH SSO not working

Tags: active-directory, ssh, kerberos, sssd, ubuntu-16.04

I have a very well working SSO Setup for Ubuntu 14.04. Unfortunately my setup does not work with Ubuntu 16.04 and I have no idea why.

I'm using sssd-ad in combination with ssh for single-sign-on, my problem is, that automatically login is not working - I always get a password prompt and with my password I'm able to login, but that's not the goal of sso...

**krb5.conf**

```
 [libdefaults]
 default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.LOC
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 dns_fallback = yes

 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 default_tkt_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
 default_tgs_enctypes = aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96
 rdns = false

 ignore_acceptor_hostname = true  # Needed with 16.04 - else I get the error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information\nNo key table entry found matching host/HOSTNAME@
```

**sssd.conf**

```
[sssd]
domains = MY.DOMAIN.LOC
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/MY.DOMAIN.LOC]
#debug_level = 0x0200
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad

ad_domain = MY.DOMAIN.LOC
krb5_realm = MY.DOMAIN.LOC

# Uncomment if the client machine hostname doesn't match the computer object on the DC.
# ad_hostname = HOSTNAME.MY.DOMAIN.LOC

# Uncomment if DNS SRV resolution is not working
# ad_server = DC.MY.DOMAIN.LOC

realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False

fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u

ad_access_filter = FOREST:MY.DOMAIN.LOC:(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=RES Linux Login,OU=MGMGroups,DC=MY,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOC)
```

**/etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
Port 22
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 4096
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG3
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
UsePAM yes
Ciphers +3des-cbc
HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss
# Needed for Backup in Ubuntu 16.04
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

With this setup I can connect to one of my Ubuntu 14.04 server from one of my domain joined workstations via SSH (GSSAPI)

**SSH Logs - Debuglevel3**

```
Client protocol version 2.0; client software version PuTTY_Release_0.65
Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 [preauth]
userauth-request for user USERNAME service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
input_userauth_request: try method none [preauth]
userauth_finish: failure partial=0 next methods="publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,keyboard-interactive" [preauth]
PAM: initializing for "USERNAME"
PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.99.99.99"
PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
userauth-request for user USERNAME service ssh-connection method gssapi-with-mic [preauth]
attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
input_userauth_request: try method gssapi-with-mic [preauth]
mm_request_send entering: type 42 [preauth]
mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 43 [preauth]
mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
mm_request_receive entering
monitor_read: checking request 42
mm_request_send entering: type 43
send packet: type 60 [preauth]
Postponed gssapi-with-mic for USERNAME from 10.99.99.99 port 65071 ssh2 [preauth]
receive packet: type 50 [preauth]
userauth-request for user USERNAME service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
attempt 2 failures 0 [preauth]
input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
auth2_challenge: user=USERNAME devs= [preauth]
kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam' [preauth]
auth2_challenge_start: devices pam [preauth]
kbdint_next_device: devices <empty> [preauth]
auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam' [preauth]
mm_sshpam_init_ctx [preauth]
mm_request_send entering: type 104 [preauth]
mm_sshpam_init_ctx: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PAM_INIT_CTX [preauth]
mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 105 [preauth]
mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
mm_request_receive entering
monitor_read: checking request 104
mm_answer_pam_init_ctx
PAM: sshpam_init_ctx entering
mm_request_send entering: type 105
mm_sshpam_query [preauth]
mm_request_send entering: type 106 [preauth]
mm_sshpam_query: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PAM_QUERY [preauth]
mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 107 [preauth]
mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
mm_request_receive entering
monitor_read: checking request 106
mm_answer_pam_query
PAM: sshpam_query entering
ssh_msg_recv entering
PAM: sshpam_thread_conv entering, 1 messages
ssh_msg_send: type 1
ssh_msg_recv entering
mm_request_send entering: type 107
mm_sshpam_query: pam_query returned 0 [preauth]
send packet: type 60 [preauth]
Postponed keyboard-interactive for USERNAME from 10.99.99.99 port 65071 ssh2 [preauth]
```

Any idea why "ignore_acceptor_hostname" is needed in ubuntu 16.04?
I don't see a reason why it doesn't work, any idea what the reason could be or how I can get a good error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was an issue with the joining to ad, in Ubuntu 16.04 "realm join" doesn't recognize the right fqdn, so the keytab file had only the hostname but not the fqdn assigned.

Solution was:

1. leaving the domain
2. set hostname to fqdn
3. rejoin the domain

That easy....